# Activities endpoint returns action field null in Directus V8

Tags: directus

I am using `Directus v8` as a headless CMS. Its self hosted. I have created content types and contents. Then when I want to view my content, I get a javascript exception which indicates `activities endpoint returns action field null` [as you see in first the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8TVk.png)

I checked the `directus_activity` table to see if action column is really null but It was ok.
Then I checked the response from activities endpoint and I saw that action field is coming null from the endpoint [as you see in the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CywYu.png)

What could be the reason for that? We have another instance of Directus and its working fine for it.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: could you please truncate `directus_activity` table and try again? (backup the table if you want to track activities)

Comment: I deleted all records from `directus_activity`, but no use